# Shell script to periodically check if a folder contains files with certain strings and if not send a mail

Tags: shell, directory

i need to write a script for work on CentOS that checks periodically (maybe every 3 hours) if a folder contains files with certain strings in the filename (like customer1 and customer2) and if not it should send a mail to a certain address.

I already found out how to find files with a certain string in the filename:

```html
#!/bin/bash

source="/FILES/user/directory1"

string="customer1"

for file in "$source"/*; do
  if [[ $file =~ $string ]]; then

    echo "do something"

  fi
done
```

How do I periodically check and how do I look for more than one string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your server must be able to send mails using any MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), I mean having connection to an SMTP server and have MTA files configured...

I will supose that your server has postfix configured and it is working, I'd rather use `find` command for your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Source="/FILES/user/directory1"
string="customer1"
mail="yourmail@maildomain.com"

Count=$(find $Source -type f -name "$string" | wc -l)

if [ "$Count" -gt 0 ]
        then
        echo "Number of files matching $string is $Count"
else
        echo "Sending mail to $mail, files don't match with customer string"
        echo "Filenames don't match with $string" | sendmail -t $mail
fi
```

If you want this check every 3 hours I'd rather recommend to configure a cronjob like this in new file `/etc/cron.d/checkFiles`

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
0 */3 * * *     root   YourScriptLocation.sh >> /var/log/checkFiles.log 2>&1
```

I've configured cronjob with root user, although you can configure job with any user that has permissions to execute script, check files in `$Source` directory and sendmail.

Comment: I up voted your answer, but you missed the vital requirement. That is if a particular string is available in the file only than send the mail not when the file arrives. I modified your answer and repost it. Please verify. Thanks

Comment: Nope, I think he requested to check only in the filename... I don't see why you should use a grep... Although I misunderstood the question, he requested to send email if check doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding the missing requirement to the answer of Alvaro Nino. Please see my comment in the code to understand how this script is working.

```
#!/bin/bash
Source="/FILES/user/directory1"
file="customer*" #Not only single file all customer files need to search
string="yoursearchstring" 
mail="yourmail@maildomain.com"

Count=$(find $Source -type f -name "$file" |xargs grep [y]oursearchstring | wc -l)
#Above command find files with name "customer*" in current directory as well as in all 
#sub directories inside the parent directory and provide each file as parameter to 
#grep command. grep command will search for the string in each file and wc-l will finally 
#count the number of occurrence of the string in it
if [ "$Count" -gt 0 ]
        then
        echo "Sending mail to $mail, number of files matching $Count"
        echo "Number of files matching $string is $Count" | sendmail -t  $mail
else
     echo "Files doesn't match with string"
fi
```